# How to draw a line passing through a point and parallel to another?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw a line passing through a point and parallel to another?

```
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
\node (A) at (1,1);
```

I need `\draw (0,1) -- (1,1);` parallel to first line.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `calc` library to calculate the vector between the first two points. By using the `+` path operator, you can draw a line from a third point in the direction of this vector:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\node [dot=A] at (2,1) {};
\node [dot=B] at (3,2) {};
\node [dot=P] at (2,2) {};

\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (A) -- (B);
\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (P) -- +($(B)-(A)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: parallel lines with TikZ]

Comment: I found the same output can be found using `++` instead of `+`. Is there any technical difference between both cases?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou yes: "instead of two plus signs, you can also add a single one. This also specifies a point in a relative
manner, but it does not “change” the current point used in subsequent relative commands. For example, `(1,0) +(1,0) +(0,1)` specifies the three coordinates `(1,0)`, then `(2,0)`, and `(1,1)`." On the other hand, "`(1,0) ++(1,0) ++(0,1)` specifies the three coordinates `(1,0)`, then `(2,0)`, and `(2,1)`." ([tikz documenation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) page 119)

Comment: @Jake I am not familiar with  `($(B)-(A)$)`;  what is that for? thks.

Comment: @mario `($(B)-(A$)` is a calculated coordinate, `$..$` is calculation mode in tikz, loaded by `calc` library. In it you can perform basic coordinate calculations such as the one presented and some more daring too. `($(B)-(A)$)` is literaly `(B)` coordinate minus `(A)` coordinate, in geometry that gives the vector pointing from `A` to `B`, that's why the line `P` is drawn is parallel to `(A)--(B)`.