# Tikz: Calculations with coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, calc

Inspired by the question [How to draw a line passing through a point and parallel to another?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19381) I'm trying to do some arithmetic with coordinates. The code below does not work, but I hope that with a small change it will. 
Basically

- in `%Q1`, I'm trying to add a vector (1,1) to (x) to obtain (y)
- in `%Q2`, I'm trying to add a vector defined by a distance 1.5 and an angle 270° to (x) to obtain (y)
- `%Q3` is the same as `%Q2` in another context (probably the same syntax also)

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={$#1$},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\node [dot=x] at (0,0) {};
% --------
%\node [dot=y] at (x) +($(1,1)$) {};        %Q1
%\node [dot=y] at (x) +($(1.5;270)$) {};    %Q2
\node [dot=y] at (x) ++(1.5;270) {};        %Q2
% --------
\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (x) -- (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\ccordinate (a) at (0,0);
\ccordinate (b) at (a)+(2;45);              %Q3
\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? you need help correcting your code?  `ccordinate` should `coordinate`, `(2;45)` should be `(2,45)`, by syntax for `calc` you must write `\coordinate (b) at ($(a)+(2,45)$);` I recommend you read the basic of TikZ first

Comment: 1. for polar coordiantes you should use a `:` instead of `;`.  2. You should do the coordinate operations inisde `$..$`.  3. There are some typo -  it's `\coordinate` not `\ccordinate`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments, here the answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm,
  dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={$#1$},name=#1},
  dott/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\node [dot=x] at (0,0) {};
\node [dot=y] at ($(x)+(45:2)$) {};
\node [dot=z] at ($(x)+(1,0)$) {};
\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (x) -- (y);
\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (x) -- (z);

\coordinate (a) at (2,0);
\coordinate (b) at ($(a)+(-45:1)$);
\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (a) -- (b);
\node[dott] at (a) {};
\node at (a) [above right = 0.7mm of a] {$a$};
\node[dott] at (b) {};
\node at (b) [above] {$b$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]